# How do I set default product attribute?

Tags: commerce

Simple Question here I hope.

I've got a Format taxonomy field on my product type Record that's defining an attribute (cd, vinyl, download etc.).

I'd like to have the same order and default value on the attribute dropdown on product displays. I've set the terms in the vocabulary in the order I want on product displays but it still seems the order is random when browsing the site...

any ideas?

Comment: Are you wanting to set the default-selected product entity on the product display or the order of the attributes?

Comment: Both actually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Ryan, [it's based on the weight of the terms you reference](https://www.drupal.org/node/1309532).

As far as the default product that is selected, it should be the first product referenced in the field. If you're wanting to set that dynamically, you can look at [Commerce Product URLs](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_urls) which provides that functionality.